# How to prevent onViewCreated when swipe through viewpager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

In my android application, I have 3 Fragments.A,B,C.When I swipe like B->C->A , onViewCreated method get called in fragment A so the application gets slow.I want to stop this onViewCreated getting called on page swipe. How can we make onViewCreated only get called at once when Mainactivity is created.Thanks in advance..

Main Activity=>

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    private ProgressDialog pd;
    Button settings;
    static TextView flashnews;
    public static int stopflag=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Headlines.parse();


        SharedPreferences mlmprf = getSharedPreferences("malayalam", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor mlmedit = mlmprf.edit();

        if(mlmprf.getBoolean("enable", true))
     {
         Headlines.headflag="malayalam";
     }
     else
     {
         Headlines.headflag="english";
     }





       flashnews=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.flashs);
       flashnews.setSelected(true);
       flashnews.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
       flashnews.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
       flashnews.setSingleLine(true);
       flashnews.setLines(1);


        ;




                PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);
        pagerTabStrip.setDrawFullUnderline(true);
        pagerTabStrip.setTabIndicatorColor(Color.rgb(174, 1, 34));



        // We get UI references
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
    }
 private class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
 private Context mContext;
        private String[] frags = {A.class.getName(), B.class.getName(),C.class.getName()};

        public MyAdapter(FragmentActivity activity) {
            super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;
        }



        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, frags[pos]);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return frags.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int pos) {

            if(pos==0)
            return "A";

            if(pos==1)
            return "B";

            if(pos==2)
            return "C";

            else
            return null;


        }

    }
}
```

Fragment A=>

```
  public class A extends Fragment{


    public static String urls;
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_HEAD = "item"; // parent node
    //static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_DATE = "pubDate";
    public static String headflag="english";
    public static String[] Title;
    public static String[] Description;
    public static String[] Tit;
    public static String[] Tit2;
    public static String[] Desc;
    public static String[] Desc2;
    public static String[] image;
    int f=0;
    GridView list;
    HeadlinesAdapter adapter;
    private TextView mMessageView;
    private Button mClearButton;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newsList; 


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflating layout
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.headlines_fragment, container, false);
        // We obtain layout references

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // We set clear listener


        if(Headlines.headflag=="malayalam")
        {
            urls="http://www.abc.com/rssfeeds/19_18_17_25/1/rss.xml";


        }

        if(Headlines.headflag=="english")
        {
            urls="http://www.abc.com/en/rssfeeds/1_2_3_5/latest/rss.xml";


        }



        parse();
        populate_listview();    
    }


     public void populate_listview()
     {


        newsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(urls); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_HEAD);
        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        NodeList itemLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
        String MarqueeStr="";

        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            newsList.add(map);
            //MarqueeStr = MarqueeStr +" *** "+ Title[i];


     }

        list=(GridView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.grid);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
                 adapter=new HeadlinesAdapter(getActivity(), newsList);        
                 list.setAdapter(adapter);



    }

  public void parse()
     {

            URL url;

            try {

                url = new URL(urls);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                if((conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)){
                      DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                      DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                      Document doc;
                      doc = db.parse(url.openStream());
                      doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                      NodeList itemLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
                      Description = new String[itemLst.getLength()];//........
                      Title = new String[itemLst.getLength()];
                      Tit=new String[itemLst.getLength()];
                      Tit2=new String[itemLst.getLength()];
                      Desc=new String[itemLst.getLength()];
                      Desc2=new String[itemLst.getLength()];
                      image= new String[itemLst.getLength()];

                      for(int i=0; i < itemLst.getLength(); i++){

                            Node item = itemLst.item(i);
                            if(item.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                                  Element ielem = (Element)item;
                                  NodeList title = ielem.getElementsByTagName("title");
                                  NodeList date = ielem.getElementsByTagName("pubDate");
                                  NodeList description = ielem.getElementsByTagName("description");
                                  Tit[i]= title.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                                  Desc[i]= description.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                                  Tit2[i]=Translate.title(Tit[i]);
                                  Desc2[i]=Translate.description(Desc[i]);
                                  if(Headlines.headflag=="malayalam")
                                    {
                                      Desc2[i]=Desc2[i].replace("read more","IqSpXÂ");
                                    }
                                  Title[i] =Tit2[i];
                                  if (Desc2[i].contains("<img ")){
                                      String img  = Desc2[i].substring(Desc2[i].indexOf("<img "));
                                      String cleanUp = img.substring(0, img.indexOf(">")+1);
                                      img = img.substring(img.indexOf("src=") + 5);
                                      int indexOf = img.indexOf("'");
                                      if (indexOf==-1){
                                          indexOf = img.indexOf("\"");
                                        }
                                      img = img.substring(0, indexOf);

                                //setImgLink(img);
                                    if(Headlines.headflag=="malayalam")
                                    {
                                        String img2=img.replace("files","files/imagecache/android_320");
                                        Description[i]=Desc2[i].replace(img,img2);
                                        image[i]=img2;
                                    }

                                else
                                {
                                    String img2=img.replace("files","files/imagecache/android_1_img");
                                    Description[i]=Desc2[i].replace(img,img2);
                                    image[i]=img2;
                                }
                                  }
                                else
                                {
                                    Description[i] =Desc2[i];
                                }



                            }

                          }

                        }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (DOMException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
     }





}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this myself by setting  viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3)...

Comment: accept your answer then to close this question. or delete it if it was trivial.